# QT Switching window transparency off

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

I have following problem. I switched on the transparency of the QWidget (top-level) with

```
setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
```

and it is all good. The window (QWidget) had a system shadow around it and it dissapeared and it was good as well. However now I need to switch the transparency off and it can be done with:

```
setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground, false);
```

But I would like to have the shadow back, but it doesn't appear. I'm using linux. Do you know how to enable the shadow?